# How do I host Ethereum on a server?

Tags: clients, nodes, solc, server-side, hosting

I recently tried to get geth and solidity up and running on a virtual server I have some free time on.

I got stuck trying to build the Solidity compiler due to issues with the OpenGL library. I've been told this is due to the fact that most virtual servers don't have graphics cards, which makes sense. I know there are some workarounds for getting OpenGL running, but I feel perhaps I'm just missing something.

What is the standard for ethereum? What environments do most people use?

Comment: Solidity should not require OpenGL. Can you update your question with specific errors that you're getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways you can run Ethereum:

- [PyEthApp](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp) Python version
- [GoEthereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) Go Version (Probably the most popular)
- [EthereumJ](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj) Java version
- [Web3 umbrella](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella) C++ version

All of the above are developed under the Ethereum project an have detailed installation instructions. So I think it really depends on what you want/need.

If you're trying to get a sense of what other folks are running you can look at [Ethstats](https://ethstats.net/). This will show you versions of Ethereum and the Operating Systems many are using.

Comment: You forgot [Parity](https://ethcore.io/parity)

Comment: Is ethereumj secure for big project?